$\int \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dA} = (E)(A)$?
I've seen this kind of simplification done very frequently in Gauss's law problems, assuming E is only radial and follows some "simple" geometry:
$$\oint\vec{E}\cdot\vec{dA}=\frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$$
$$\oint |\vec{E}|\hat{r} \cdot \hat{r} dA = \frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$$
$$\int|\vec{E}| dA = \frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$$
I understand up to here. What I don't understand is the next step:
$$\int|\vec{E}| dA = |\vec{E}| \int dA = \frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$$
Why can we just take $|\vec{E}|$ out of the integral? I've heard the argument that "it's because E doesn't depend on A", but then we could just express everything in terms of $r$ (for the following line I'm just using a point charge for simplicity):
$$\int \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r^2}rdrd\theta$$When put in this form, $|\vec{E}|=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r^2}$, but no one in their right mind would say that this doesn't depend on $r$ and is thus constant under integration w.r.t. $dr$ and $d\theta$. Therefore we obviously shouldn't take $|\vec{E}|$ out of the integral in this case...yet if we do, the whole thing still gives the right answer...

If you're integrating over a surface over which $r$ varies (or, more generally, over which $|\vec{E}|$ varies, then you're correct that you couldn't pull it out of the integral.
So it's a good thing that we don't use such a surface.  For a spherically symmetric charge, for example, we use a surface of constant $r$, and the symmetry of the situation tells us that $|\vec{E}|$ is the same over the entire surface.  (Your integration element in this case would be $r^2 \sin \theta \, d \theta \, d \phi$;  and you wouldn't be integrating over $r$.)
Similar arguments apply to the cylindrical or pillbox Gaussian surfaces used in cases of cylindrical or planar symmetry.

OHHHHHHHH I see. So because we're computing a surface integral over $\vec{E}$, which is constant over the surface (if we chose the right one), we can pull it out?

It sounds like you are assuming a situation where $\vec{E}=E(r)\hat{r}$, where $E(r)$ a scalar function that depends only on the radial coordinate (and not on the angular coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$).  Now, if you choose your Gaussian integration surface to be spherical, then you are holding $r$ constant and integrating only over the spherical coordinates.  i.e., the area element is $dA=r^2\sin\theta\, d\theta d\phi$.  Notice there is no $dr$.  You are treating $r$ as constant by integrating over the surface of a sphere with fixed $r$.  Since $E(r)$ does not depend on the angular coordinates, you may pull it out of the angular integrals.  Note this only applies to integration done over the surface of a sphere.  If you had picked a non-spherical Gaussian surface, then you cannot simply pull $E(r)$ out of the integral.  You'd have to do the integral.  The miracle of Gauss's law says that doing this much more difficult non-spherical integral would still give you $Q_{enc}/\epsilon_0$, but it would require a lot more (unnecessary) work to get the same result.
In situations where we know the field will have some symmetry, we deliberately choose our Gaussian surface so as to take advantage of the kind of simplification observed here.  Often, rather than using Gauss's law to calculate the enclosed charge by integrating the electric field, we actually want to use Gauss's law to derive a formula for the electric field in terms of the enclosed charge.  Presumably, whatever source you are referencing is using Gauss's law to get an expression for $E(r)$ in terms of the enclosed charge in situations where the enclosed charge is spherically symmetric.

Why can we just take $|\vec E|$ out of the integral?
If the electric field is uniform and perpendicular over the chosen area then $|\vec E|$ can be taken out of the integral.
In the case of a point charge then at a distance from the point charge the electric field is $\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r^2}$ and the integral of the area is $4\pi r^2$ which leads to the correct answer as to the electric flux.
Also think of a plane which is perpendicular to the electric field between charged parallel plates.
